# Check if an HTML string only has element children (or whitespace between elements) and no element is unknown

Tags: javascript, html

I try to test if a string contains some HTML text with some specific properties:

- Everything at the top level needs to be wrapped in a tag, so `"<div>abc</div><div>xyz</div>"` is valid, but `"<div>abc</div> 123 <div>xyz</div>"` is not. Whitespace between tags is fine.
- Every tag needs to be an existing HTML tag, so `"<div></div><x></x>"` or `"<div><x></x></div>"` are both invalid since `<x></x>` is an unknown tag.

```js
console.log(/(&lt;|<)br\s*\/?(&gt;|>)|(<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>)/.test('<br/> span>test<span>'))

// test <br/> -> (&lt;|<)br\s*\/?(&gt;|>)
// test the rest tags -> (<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>)
```

Also, I tried using `DOMParser`:

```js
function isValidHTML(html) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

  if (doc.documentElement.querySelector("parsererror")) {
    return doc.documentElement.querySelector("parsererror").innerText;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isValidHTML("<span>test</span> 123 <p>ss</p>"))
```

Here, I expect an error, but it returns `true`.

According to the code, I expect to get `false`, because my code is not “valid” HTML. How to fix the code?

Comment: How exactly do you define “valid”? Regular expressions are going to be the wrong tool to use. Use [`DOMParser`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [`XMLSerializer`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, so, how to achieve what i want?

Comment: [HTML cannot be parsed with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @SebastianSimon, i need to parse a string, and to check if it is a valid html, so i don't parse html, but string

Comment: That's why DOMParser has method `parseFromString`

Comment: @skyboyer, i added an example but it does not work

Comment: @skyboyer, could you help please?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, i added an example in the question but it does not work, could you help plesae?

Comment: I think you want to use `text/html` instead of `text/xml`

Comment: @skyboyer, i changed, but anyway i get true, but `123` is not a tag, it does not have a tag wrapper. Why i get true?

Comment: then I don't get what the definition of "valid html" means in this case. Text nodes are definitely valid for HTML.

Comment: the example does not contain `</span>` closing tag. That's why probably it interprets 123 as in a tag

Comment: @ilkerkaran, i changed, but the same issue still there

Comment: @skyboyer, i want to check if each string is wrapped in html tag.

Comment: "i want to check if each string is wrapped in html tag" - that is a totally different requirement than what I think most of us understood so far...

Comment: @PeterB, what do you mean? I want to check if the string that contains html is a valid html, meaning all html tags are valid, all text have open and close tag.

Comment: Your example is valid html

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, what do you mean?

Comment: `<span>test</span> 123 <p>ss</p>` is valid html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that something like `<div>abc</div> 123 <div>xyz</div>` *is a valid HTML fragment*.
Checking for your requirements and checking if an HTML string is something that would commonly be referred to as “valid” are two very different things.

Your requirements ask for a function that I’m going to call `htmlStringHasElementOrWhitespaceChildrenAndNoUnknownElements`.
Because, what you’re looking for is

- a function that takes a string (an HTML string, presumably), and returns a boolean based on if the HTML string has certain properties. (`htmlStringHas`…)
- Those properties are:

  - The [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node), when parsed from the string, consist of either [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element), or of [Text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Text) which contain only whitespace. These Nodes are all at the root of the parsed structure.<sup>1</sup> (…`ElementOrWhitespaceRoots`…)
  - The Elements are all defined in HTML. (…`AndNoUnknownElements`)

This is a function that checks for these properties:

```js
const htmlStringHasElementOrWhitespaceRootsAndNoUnknownElements = (string) => {
    const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html").body;
    
    return Array.from(parsed.childNodes)
        .every(({ nodeType, textContent }) => (nodeType === Document.ELEMENT_NODE || nodeType === Document.TEXT_NODE) && (nodeType !== Document.TEXT_NODE || !textContent.trim()))
      && Array.from(parsed.querySelectorAll("*"))
        .every((node) => !(node instanceof HTMLUnknownElement));
  };

console.log(htmlStringHasElementOrWhitespaceChildrenAndNoUnknownElements("<br><span>test</span> test <div>aa8<x></x><y>asd</y></div>")); // false
```

[`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is used to check validity on every Node.

Alternatively, if you want to *remove* those “invalid” nodes, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and call the `remove` method (either for [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) or for [CharacterData nodes, which Texts inherit from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData/remove)) on each node using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
Array.from(parsed.childNodes)
  .filter(({ nodeType, textContent }) => (nodeType !== Document.ELEMENT_NODE && nodeType !== Document.TEXT_NODE) || (nodeType === Document.TEXT_NODE && textContent.trim()))
  .concat(Array.from(parsed.querySelectorAll("*"))
    .filter((node) => node instanceof HTMLUnknownElement))
  .forEach((node) => node.remove());
```

I’ve started by filtering the set of valid nodes, then negated the predicate, and simplified using De Morgan’s laws.

Since the function name is unwieldy, let’s abbreviate that to `validHTMLString` for now, although you must document what you define as “valid”.

Some test cases:

```js
validHTMLString("<div></div><div></div>"); // true
validHTMLString("<x></x>"); // false
validHTMLString("<div><x></x></div>"); // false
validHTMLString("<img/> <span>test</span>"); // true
validHTMLString("a <div>b</div> c"); // false
```

Please note that there are some major caveats with this:

First, you’ve been asking about “valid” HTML for a while, but usually “valid HTML” means “conforms to the HTML specification”, which can be checked by an [HTML validator](https://html5.validator.nu/).
This is non-trivial to check by yourself, since `DOMParser` will apply exactly the same fixes to broken HTML that your browser will apply for *any* website it encounters.
Something like `validHTMLString("<p><p></p></p><input></input><span>")` will therefore result in `true`, despite containing three errors (or four errors, as the validator counts).
But `DOMParser` is the best tool we have, other than writing our own validator from scratch or searching for an existing one.
Regular expressions are guaranteed to be insufficient for the purpose of validating arbitrary HTML strings.

You could attempt comparing the result of serializing the parsed result with the original string, but the serialization includes unrelated fixes which don’t cause a validation error. Example: tags like `<img/>` are serialized as `<img />`.

Second, [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) exist.
Something like `<my-element>` may be a valid element, with its own class, derived from `HTMLElement`, after it has been defined.

---

<sup>1</sup>: When `DOMParser` parses HTML, it will try to create a valid HTML document. Your root nodes are the `childNodes` of the created `body`.